# Problema al extraer el mayor numero SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente tabla DATOS

```
CUENTA    FECHA    STATUS
4053    08/05/2020  1
4053    08/05/2020  3
4053    08/05/2020  9
4295    08/05/2020  4
4295    08/05/2020  1
2952    08/05/2020  7
2952    08/05/2020  1
5288    08/05/2020  8
5288    08/05/2020  7
5288    08/05/2020  1
5288    08/05/2020  1
```

La regla es solo obtener los registros con status 1, 4, 8 por cada cuenta. Y en el caso en donde existan dos estatus de los permitidos en la misma fecha solo extraer el más alto. Es decir en este caso:

```
Cuenta      Fecha       Estatus
5288    08/05/2020       8
5288    08/05/2020       7
5288    08/05/2020       1
```

Solo debería obtener la fila de estatus 8.

Tengo el siguiente query el cual si obtiene el estatus mayor en el caso en donde existe una cuenta con estatus 1,4 (Solo obtiene el 4). Pero en el caso donde la cuenta tiene 1,7,8 extrae los registros con estatus 1 y 8.

```
Select cuenta, fecha, max(status)
from DATOS
where to_char(fecha, 'dd/mm/yy') = '08/05/20'
and status in (1,4,8)
GROUP BY cuenta, fecha
order by cuenta
```

Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. El SQL parece correcto... ¿seguro que no es un problema con los datos? Por ejemplo, que en uno de los registros la cuenta sea '5288 ' (con un espacio en blanco). Prueba haciendo "select '+'||cuenta||'+' ..." (concatenar un '+' delante y detras de cuenta) a ver si sale algo por el estilo.

Comment: No, parece que el problema es la fecha, si quito la fecha del grupo by obtiene los registros correctos. Sin embargo si lo quito, también tendría que eliminarlo del select y necesito también la información de fecha. :(

Comment: ¿Puede ser que la fecha tenga información de horas, minutos, segundos? Mira haciendo un "select to_char(fecha, 'dd/MM/yy HH24:MI:SS')"

Comment: Si, justo los registros con estatus 8 tienen información de horas, minutos y segundos.

Comment: Pues eso, al hacer el "group by" esos registros son distintos, y por lo tanto no te los agrupa. O bien haces que el tipo de dato solo refleje la fecha (si es lo que toca en tu modelo), o haces el group by por "to_char(fecha, 'dd/mm/yy')" para que tengan exactamente el mismo valor y te los agrupe

Comment: Muchas gracias... Quedó solucionado!

Comment: Convierte to fecha desde el inicio: ´Select cuenta, to_char(fecha, 'dd/mm/yy'), max(status)´. Para convertir una fecha según el formato que le pongas, tienes que hacerlo desde el inicio.